# useEffect infinite loop with redux toolkit dispatch and fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using **redux-toolkit** in react, i have a loading state for the entire app. In a component I'm doing a function to dispatch the loading to true then fetch data then dispatch loading to false. Then putting that function in a useEffect. Here's the code:

```
const getUsers = async () => {
      try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const req = await axios.get(URL);
      const res = req.data;
      setUsers(res);
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
      console.log("data fetched");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
```

The **problem** is that the useEffect is running infinitely non-stop.

- If i remove the 2nd dispatch in the function(*dispatch(setLoading(false))*), it works and useEffect runs once. or even if i keep the 1st dispatch and keep the 2nd it also works.
- If i remove the data fetching and just keep the two dispatch, it works.

why is this happening? at first i thought it's because running two dispatch but then it seems related to combining fetching with these. I do this in basic redux and never faced a problem like this one.

Comment: have you tried to wrap your ```getusers``` with a useCallback hook to maintain single instance between renderings?

Comment: @Amr I did try but nothing changed

Comment: Is this component unmounting when the loading state is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem isn't with redux-toolkit but a mistake i've made with react-router v6.

Comment: Can you please share what was the issue and fix it? I am facing a similar issue.